# How to recreate website content in an app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

After a few hours of searching and trying to do it on my own, I'm afraid I've run out of options and I have to ask for help.
I want to make everything from [this](http://tools.dboglobal.com/dbo_skill_calculator/?tool=Skill-Calculator&class=Fighter)
page available in an app, even if the user is offline.
I tried copying those small pictures and using them as buttons but then i couldn't put those numbers next to them. A lot of people told me to use WebView but as far as I know, it'd require internet access which isn't my goal here.

Please help if you can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Declare that you are not promoting that web page of yours first! :D
Anyways, you could go the hybrid app way - use Cordova, ionic or Phonegap

Comment: I'm not promoting it :D.I'm sorry if it's against the rules, I didn't know.
Thanks, I think Phonegap could help

Answer (score 1):

You can build a hybrid app, if it's Web technologies that you are more familiar with than Android. Ionic is one of them, used for developing web apps. All you need to know is the web technologies.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions to your problem is fully download the page's source files and then use method

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourfullHTMLwithCSSandJShere, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

so you just give a site's source as string parameter to the webview

Answer (score 1):

Copy your .html page in assets folder of your android project and use the given code to load page form assets folder.

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog loading;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //code for ads
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //casting view
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


        //load URL in webView
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hindi.html");

        //start progress dialog
        loading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        loading.setMessage("Loading...");
        loading.show();

        //webView client
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                loading.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error:" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menus, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hindi.html");
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/english.html");
                return true;

            case R.id.item3:
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentDialog dialogFragment = new FragmentDialog();
                dialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
                dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample FragmentDialog");
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    //save and restore state of application
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
        // killed and restarted.
        // etc.

        savedInstanceState.putLong("elapsedTime", 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

        long elapsedTime = savedInstanceState.getLong("elapsedTime");
    }
}
```

I load url in OptionsMenu you load your url where ever you want and internet is not required for this.